# Javascript code doesn't work in my wordpress theme

Tags: javascript

Hi my java script code doesn't work in my `wordpress` theme i enqueue my `scripts.js` file what is the problem and what is the expected behaviour?

```
    function my_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'responsive', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/responsive.css' , array() );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js', array(),  true );

} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

`scripts.js` file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    /*------ Masonry ------*/
    $(".post-four.grid .row").masonry({
        itemSelector: ".post",
        horizontalOrder: true
    });

    /*------ Search button ------*/
    let hasFocus = false;
    $(".header-top .header-search .searchform i").click(function() {
        const setState = hasFocus ? 'blur' : 'focus';
        $('.header-top .header-search .searchform #s')[setState]();
        hasFocus = !hasFocus;
    });
    let hasFocusTwo = false;
    $(".header-sticky-inner .header-search i").click(function() {
        const setStateTwo = hasFocusTwo ? 'blur' : 'focus';
        $('.header-sticky-inner .header-search #input-search')[setStateTwo]();
        hasFocusTwo = !hasFocusTwo;
    });

    /*------ Sidebar ------*/
    $(".sidebar-button #sidebarButton").click(function(){
        $("body").addClass("sidebar-active");
    });
    $(".sidebar-right #closebtn").click(function(){
        $("body").removeClass("sidebar-active");
    });
    $("#content-bg").click(function(){
        $("body").removeClass("sidebar-active");
    });
    $(".sidebar-button-menu #sidebarButton").click(function(){
        $("body").addClass("sidebar-active-menu");
    });
    $(".sidebar-menu #closebtn").click(function(){
        $("body").removeClass("sidebar-active-menu");
    });
    $("#content-bg").click(function(){
        $("body").removeClass("sidebar-active-menu");
    });

    /*------ Drop Down Menu ------*/
    let dropdown = $(".has-child a");
    let i;

    for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
        dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            let dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
                dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    }

    /*------ Grid Tab ------*/
    $('.grid-tab > li > a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).closest('.grid-tab > li').toggleClass('active-li')
        .siblings('.grid-tab > li').removeClass('active-li');
    });

    /*------ Scroll ------*/
    let previousScroll = 0;
    let memoScroll = $("header").height() - $(".header-sticky").height();
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        let scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrolled > memoScroll){
            if (scrolled < previousScroll){
                $(".header-sticky").addClass("visible");
            } else {
                $(".header-sticky").removeClass("visible");
            }
        }else {
                $(".header-sticky").removeClass("visible");
        }
        previousScroll = scrolled;
    });

});

/*------ OWL Carousel ------*/
$(".owl-instagram, .owl-category, .owl-post-wg").owlCarousel({
    items:1,
    dots:true
});
$(".sidebar-right .owl-instagram,.sidebar-right .owl-category,.sidebar-right .owl-post-wg").owlCarousel({
    items:1,
    dots:true
});
$(".owl-instagram-feed").owlCarousel({
    items:5,
    dots:false,
    nav: true,
    navText: ['<i class="ion-android-arrow-back"></i>','<i class="ion-android-arrow-forward"></i>'],
    loop: true,
    responsiveClass: true,
    responsive: {
        0:{
            items:2
        },
        576:{
            items:3
        },
        768:{
            items:4
        },
        992:{

        }
    }
});
$(".owl-slider").owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    nav: true,
    navText: ['<i class="ion-android-arrow-back"></i>','<i class="ion-android-arrow-forward"></i>'],
    dots: true,
    mouseDrag: false
});
$(".owl-slider-center").owlCarousel({
    items: 2,
    center: true,
    margin: 10,
    loop: true,
    nav: true,
    navText: ['<i class="ion-android-arrow-back"></i>','<i class="ion-android-arrow-forward"></i>'],
    dots: false,
    mouseDrag: true,
    removeClass: true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            center:false,
            items:1
        },
        576:{
            items:1,
            center:false
        },
        768:{
            items:1,
            center:false
        },
        992:{

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have errors in console?

Comment: There's a lot of code here, does none of it work? I notice you're trying to use Owl Carousel and Masonry, but don't see you enqueueing their files anywhere.

Comment: @morteza-yung check your browsers developer tools, the console should contain error messages for your javascript. Also Owl carousel is abandoned, consider using a maintained carousel library

Answer (score 1):

First - set `jquery` in dependencies array. And if you are using libraries - include them.
All libraries must be registered, not enqueue. Use `wp_register_script();`. And set libs in dependencies array.

```
wp_register_script('my-masonry', 'path to lib', array(), null, true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js', array('jquery', 'my-masonry'),  null, true );
```

Code like this must fix your issue.
And also..

Wrap your code in this

```
(function($){
    // your code
})(jQuery);
```

instead `jQuery(document).ready(function($){});`

And use more unique handles (names) for your scripts. Because some plugins can register and enqueue scripts with similar name.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to depend on multiple libraries, so you need to list them as dependencies to make sure WordPress loads them so they are available before your script.

To require dependencies, you need to include their handles in the array you pass as the 3rd arguement in `wp_enqueue_script()`.

- Your script uses jQuery and Masonry, which are both bundled in WP core and can be required with their respective handles: `jquery` and `jquery-masonry` (or `masonry`for the native JS version).
- Your script also uses Owl Carousel, which is not bundled in WP core so you'll need to make sure this is loaded on your site, and require it as a dependency.

Let's say you have Owl Carousel registered with the handle `'owlcarousel'`, then your call to `wp_enqueue_script()` should be:

```
wp_enqueue_script(
    'my-scripts',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js',
    array( 'jquery', 'jquery-masonry', 'owlcarousel' ),
    true
);
```

If Owl Carousel is not already present in your theme, then [download it](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/), drop `owl.carousel.min.js` in your theme's `/assets/js/` folder and register it before your script with:

```
wp_register_script(
    'owlcarousel',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js',
    array(),
    true
);
```

References:

- `wp_register_script()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/
- `wp_enqueue_script()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

This page also contains a list of scripts included in WP Core and their handles to use to require them as dependencies.